# Autofill the form using JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, html, variables, autofill

Note: Anytrack is a tracking software which automatically assigns a atclid value.. It'll be a random number like 100000000012545 and you won't get this value unless the tracking code is added on the website.

This is the code I'm using

```js
AnyTrack(function() {
var atclid = AnyTrack('atclid');

document.querySelector('input[name="checkout_offer[extra_contact_information][custom_11]"]').value = atclid ;
});
```

```html
<input class="form-control string optional " bind="custom_11" data-parsley-required-message="* Required" data-parsley-type-message="is invalid" data-parsley-group="extra_contact_information" type="text" name="checkout_offer[extra_contact_information][custom_11]" id="checkout_offer_extra_contact_information_custom_11" data-parsley-id="3067">
```

Here this code retries the atclid value

```js
AnyTrack(function() {
    var atclid = AnyTrack('atclid');

    document.querySelector('input[name="checkout_offer[extra_contact_information][custom_11]"]').value = atclid ;
    });
```

```html
<input class="form-control string optional " bind="custom_11" data-parsley-required-message="* Required" data-parsley-type-message="is invalid" data-parsley-group="extra_contact_information" type="text" name="checkout_offer[extra_contact_information][custom_11]" id="checkout_offer_extra_contact_information_custom_11" data-parsley-id="3067">
```

Comment: What is the `AnyTrack()` function? It makes little sense that you would call it with a callback function and also call it with a string argument to get `atclid`.

Comment: Note: the snippets in this question either produced errors or just a textbox when run; nothing that illustrated the issue. I've removed them. As it is, without knowing what `AnyTrack` is, there is little in the way of help we can provide. [Edit] your question to provide more info.

Comment: I've added a Note at the top of my question. Thanks @HereticMonkey

Comment: What is the problem that you are having? Your example does match their docs.

Comment: @imvain2 I'm trying to autofill this input field with the atclid value
<input class="form-control string optional " bind="custom_11" data-parsley-required-message="* Required" data-parsley-type-message="is invalid" data-parsley-group="extra_contact_information" type="text" name="checkout_offer[extra_contact_information][custom_11]" id="checkout_offer_extra_contact_information_custom_11" data-parsley-id="3067">

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to make sure that your script file is after the `body` tag, so that you can query the `input` element.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head></head>
    <body></body>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```